# Burns survival dataset - meaning of midpoint of set interval

Tags: r, survival, interval-censoring

I'm using the well-known USC Burns Survival dataset to explore logistic regression in R.

The independent variable is burn area, and the outcome is binary survival (yes/no).

In the documentation, burn areas are grouped as the 'midpoint of set intervals', and taken as a log ie.

```
log(area + 1)
```

for sample datapoints like (highest/lowest):

```
1.35    yes
2.35    no
```

Medically, burns are usually specifed in terms of surface area % of total body eg. 40%, or alternatively, as an estimate of surface area in square meters. My question is: how does this relate to the dataset independent variable ie. what does '1.35' actually mean in terms of % body surface area burnt? What would eg. 30% burns become in the dataset, using the 'midpoint of set interval'?

Thanks guys

Ref: http://statmaster.sdu.dk/courses/st111/data/index.html#burns

Comment: When I clicked the link to the dataset, the access is forbidden. Is there any link to the burns dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the original article. 'area' in the model referred to third degree burn area in square centimeters. The independent variable 'midpoint' in the dataset is thus

```
X = ln(third degree burn area cm2 + 1)
```

Ref: http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/information/library/mimeo.archive/ISMS_1992_2089.pdf

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share the answer and don't hesitate to accept it (with the little check mark next to the vote number) to mark the question as “answered”.